# Males named מיכל?

Tags: names, etymology

Where does the male name מיכל (as in יחיאל מיכל) come from? Is it a diminutive/corruption/translation/elision of מיכאל, derived therefrom in some other way, or simply a false cognate?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: Terumat HaDeshen 231 discusses this https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%9F/%D7%90/%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%90

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [Igros Moshe Orach Chaim 5:10:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14679&st=&pgnum=64&hilite=) Reb Moshe ZaTzaL writes that Michel is a Kinui (nickname) for Yechiel.

Comment: and that would explain why the combination יחיאל מיכל is so common

Comment: how does this answer the question? What is its etymology?

Answer (score 12):

> לפי תלמוד בבלי מסכת עירובין צו. מיכל בת שאול הניחה תפלין. האר"י מסביר זאת בכך שהייתה לה נשמה מעלמא דדכורא = נשמה מעולם הזכרים.‏

http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9C

Maybe that is how the name became a male name?

Comment: Wow. This is a compelling find (if not etymological)!

Comment: Very intresting

Comment: I can imagine this being used by some people nowadays to advocate certain things that most frum Jews don't support.

Answer (score 9):

Michel (emphasis on the first syllable) is a German form of Michael (says [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_%28name%29))

Comment: Agreeing with the general thrust here.  The Yiddish ['mɪxʌl] was just a corruption of "Michael", unrelated to the Hebrew girls' name [mi'xal].

Answer (score 6):

*Aruch Hashulchan*, *Even Haezer* 129, writes (in my own loose translation with uncertain translations marked with question marks in brackets [thus?]):

> [We spell the name] "יחיאל". And some are nicknamed "מיכל", so we write [in a *get*] "יחיאל, who's nicknamed מיכל". Even though מיכל is a [non-nick name?], like "מיכל בת שאול" and like "מיכל מים", still and all, this name is based on a different understanding: Earlier, they'd call יחיאל ‎"חיאל" for short; this [evolved?] into calling him "איחל", which [evolved?] into calling him "מיכל". And don't say that we should therefore write "מיחל", with a *ches*, as I've already brought the words of the *Rama* that it's better to write with a *chaf* than with a *ches* [a foreign name, "because there are places that read a *ches* like a *he* and there'll be a change in the name"], and that's how everyone practices already. However, in any event, since this isn't from the name "מיכל" which is in *Tanach*, we write "who's nicknamed" and not "who's called".

Comment: Worth noting that the _Aruch Hashulchan_ himself was named _Yechiel Michel_.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that I don't have a written source for this, however, I have heard this from several Lubavitchers, including the Rosh Yeshiva of the Tzemach Tzedek Yeshiva in Jerusalem.  Essentially the Admur of Lubavitch, in one of his sichot made a statement that the alef may be corruption of the name, and thus it should be pronounced as if the alef were not there.  I have met at one Lubavitcher that was named Michal(minus the alef) on account of that.

Comment: How in earth (no pun intended) is the name of the angel Mi-Ka-El a corruption?